# Может ли jquery создавать некий аналог map например для тега span или div?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Может ли jquery создавать некий аналог map например для тега span или div? Суть задачи следующая: есть контейнер определённой высоты и ширины, у контейнера есть фоновое изображение, мне нужно чтобы в зависимости от области в которой находится мышка над контейнером подсвечивалась определённая ссылка. Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместить на нем прозрачную картинку и добавить полноценный map, либо отслеживать координаты мыши и сравнивать с формулой фигуры.

Если области просты по форме - закрепить прозрачные блоки